# Regex with digits and some special characters

Tags: c#, regex

I need help with creating a regex that would recognize tokens in text.
Token requirements are as follows:

- should start and end with `$`
- can contain any combination of letters, digits, `_`
- can contain only one consecutive `.`, meaning:

  - `$some.valid.sample$` is valid
  - `$some..invalid.sample$` is not
- can contain square brackets, but only if they contain a number inside, meaning:

  - `$some.valid[0].sampl$` is valid
  - `$some.invalid[].sample$` is not
- contains between 1 and 64 characters

additional requirements (after discussion in comments):

- square brackets with number have to be followed by `.` if they are not at the end (i.e. if they are not just before closing `$`)
- length  constraint applies to content between two `$`

Can anyone help me out with this?
So far I have `\$([A-Za-z0-9._]*(\[\d+\])*)+]$`

Comment: Try [`\$(?:[A-Za-z0-9_]|\[\d+\])+(?:\.(?:[A-Za-z0-9_]|\[\d+\])+)*\$`](https://regex101.com/r/BAniMi/1)

Comment: I think `Regex.Matches(s, @"\$(?:\w|\[\d+])+(?:\.(?:\w|\[\d+])+)*\$", RegexOptions.ECMAScript)` will be what you need (if you only want to match ASCII letters and digits).

Comment: Do the square brackets have to occur at the end of each segment, or is `$ab[0]cd$` also valid?

Comment: Also, with the `$` at either end there must be at least two characters; does the length constraint apply to what lies between them?

Comment: Yes, maybe you need `Regex.Matches(s, @"\$(?![][\w.]{64})\w+(?:\[\d+])?(?:\.\w+(?:\[\d+])?)*\$", RegexOptions.ECMAScript)`

Comment: And also, are these valid? `$[0]$`, `$a.[1]$`, `$a[1][2]$`

Comment: @JonDavies: in order: 1) yes, they have to be at the end of segment, or to put it differently, they have to be followed by a '.' if they are not at the end (meaning - before closing '$'); 2) length constraint applies to what lies between two '$'; 3) all of those are not valid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the updated rules from the comments, this is what you need:

```
\$(?=[^\$]{1,64}\$)\w+(?:\[\d+\])?(?:\.\w+(?:\[\d+\])?)*\$
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this pattern:

```
\$\w+?.?\w*?(\[\d+\]?)?.?\w*?\$
```

You can [test it here](http://regexr.com/)

it is a little too narrow though. I would take the suggestion by @Wiktor Stribizew